# Is it okay to have Pharos port open on Ubuntu LTS 14 cloud server?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, ubuntu-14.04, cloud

I was running a port scan on my ubuntu server hosted on cloud. Here are the port scan results that showed up. I am okay with the http and https ports but I am not sure if the **pharos** port needed to be kept open. The server is meant to serve Rest API's and may be make logs available through some means. Is **pharos** necessary for server management? Can someone provide more info.

```
 Open TCP Port:     80          http
 Open TCP Port:     443         https
 Open TCP Port:     4443        pharos
```

Port Scan has completed…

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an application that requires port 4443 to be open? If not, I would close it. Your best security model begins with only opening the absolutely necessary ports.

For a standard web application only 80 and 443 would be necessary.

Comment: I am accessing rest API's and my understanding is 80 and 443 are good enough. I dont have anything else running for my app.

Comment: I would find out what has enabled 4443 and disable it. If it is an iptable rule I would delete it.